# Compact Metric Space as a Countable Union of Closed Sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, connectedness

I am becoming frustrated with an elementary problem from topology, and I need to go ahead and ask for some help.  I hope it's not as tricky as it seems.

I remember having to prove a theorem  that if $X$ is a compact metric space, such that $X$ can be written as the countable, pairwise-disjoint union of closed, connected subsets $X_n$, then each $X_n$ is a component.  Does anybody have a reference for this theorem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Naturally, once I post the question I think I've stumbled across the answer.  Seems doable using (ugh) quasi-components, but a proof avoiding that would be highly preferable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Kuratowski, "Topology", Vol. 2, p. 173-174; Theorem 6a. (The result is due to Sierpinski.)

Comment: I don't have access to this one; does the proof use the cut wire and/or boundary bumping theorem?  I am trying to avoid that, as well.

Comment: No, it does not use any of this language. The proof is about 1 page long and not completely trivial.

Comment: It uses the boundary bumping theorem.  But it's ok, it uses the easier one.  Thanks for the reference!